# Merge (combine) 2 Javascript function

Tags: javascript, function

I am new in JavaScript and have two different functions to merge (combine):
How to merge this 2 function into 1 function?

Function 1:

```
 function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
   if (x.className === "topnav") {
   x.className += " responsive";
   } else {
   x.className = "topnav";
 }
 }
```

and function 2:

```
 function myFunction(x) {
 x.classList.toggle("change");
 }
```

1. The goal: use these 2 function for your a subject.

Can someone help me on this matter?

Really appreciate for any helps..

Comment: What's the question/problem? What is the expected result? What's the relevant markup? What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1):

Struggling to know exactly why you can't combine the functions as you have written them. But here's an idea:

```
 function myFunction(element) {
   const x = element || document.getElementById("myTopnav");

   if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
   } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
   }
   
   x.classList.toggle("change");
 }
```

This makes use of [Logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR). If the `element` parameter is not undefined then its reference will be assigned to x. If the `element` parameter is undefined then x will instead be assigned the evaluation of `document.getElementById("myTopnav")`.

I would recommend trying to get in the habit of using `const` or `let` instead of `var`.

Answer (score -1):

```js
 function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
   if (x.className === "topnav") {
   x.className += " responsive";
   } else {
   x.className = "topnav";
 }
 }

// you must change the name of my funtion because you already use it
 function myFunction2(x) {
 x.classList.toggle("change");
 }

// then pass the parameter to function 2
$.extend(myFunction, myFunction2("test"));
```